# Sending data from Wordpress Contact form 7 to Laravel via Webhooks

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, laravel-8

I am very new at APIs and stuff.
I would appreciate it if anyone can help me to understand or guide me on how to accomplish the following.

I have a contact form in Wordpress with the Contact-form 7 plugin. It is a basic contact form to capture enquiries with just 3 fields i.e. Name, Contact Number & Type of Enquiry.
The data is sent to Laravel Application, and saves in Lead Management where the followups are taken care of.

I referred to some tutorials online to accomplish the following.

- I am using wp-webhooks wordpress plugin to send data to my Laravel API.
- I have created the necessary API routes and AuthController in my Laravel Application.
- Created SalesController to handle the store method.

My issue is, I am not able to get the data in my Laravel application. While testing in postman, the api works when I manually insert the type as bearer and set the token. Or when the application is logged-in in the same browser.

I dont know how to authenticate the user.

**My API Routes**

```
//API route for register new user
Route::post('/register', [App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController::class, 'register']);
//API route for login user
Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController::class, 'login']);


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
    Route::get('/profile', function(Request $request) {
    return auth()->user();
    });

// API route for Cf7 to system
Route::resource('externalsales', App\Http\Controllers\API\SalesController::class);


// API route for logout user
Route::post('/logout', [App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

**My AuthController**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors());       
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
         ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()
            ->json(['data' => $user,'access_token' => $token, 'token_type' => 'Bearer', ]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password')))
        {
            return response()
                ->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()
            ->json(['message' => 'Hi '.$user->name.', welcome to home','access_token' => $token, 'token_type' => 'Bearer', ]);
    }

    // method for user logout and delete token
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();

        return [
            'message' => 'You have successfully logged out and the token was successfully deleted'
        ];
    }
}
```

**My SalesController**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = SalesManagement::latest()->get();
    return response()->json([SalesResource::collection($data), 'Leads fetched.']);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'fullname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'mobile' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'

    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json($validator->errors());       
    }

    $sales = SalesManagement::create([
        'fullname' => $request->fullname,
        'mobile' => $request->mobile,
        'description' => $request->description,
     ]);
    $token = $request->bearerToken();

    
    return response()->json(['Lead created successfully.','access_token' => $token, 'token_type' => 'Bearer', new SalesResource($sales)]);
}
```

Comment: If your it works when you send data with postman you might send wrong request from your Wordpess application, you should clarify that how you send request to api and is both of your applications on the same network(both on local machine or on the internet)

Comment: @vahid It works only when i manually added bearer token in the request. i.e. Authorization > set it as bearer. And paste the login token obtained in the previous test login api.
or when the application is signed-in in the same browser as postman.
So i am guessing, i am not doing the authorization right. And i have no idea how to go forward.
i have only one api https://domain.dom/api/externalsales
And yes, both the sites are on internet. Wp is live and laravel on staging.

Comment: ok i suggest you read about how JWT works you can use this link https://blog.miniorange.com/what-is-jwt-json-web-token-how-does-jwt-authentication-work/ when you authenticate, if it is successful you should save the token on client side app based on your client app you can store the token in cache or store it on a database or on browser(cookie, local storage, .. ). and when you try to want to make a new request to api you should send the bearer token in the header of your request

Comment: @vahidkhroasaninejad thank you for the pointers. It was a little complicated for me to understand. Ended up putting the route outside the middleware. So there was no need for auth.